# what's the exact behavior of PopupWindow.showAtLocation?

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have an android 4.0 phone say *A*, and a 4.4 tablet say *B*, both have a software navigation bar.
I use this:

```
showAtLocation(myView, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, x, y);
```

to show the window at a specific location. The actual result is, it looks ok on *A* but has a y offset on *B*. I find that the offset appears to be the same height as *B*'s navigation bar. So I use the following code to get the height and do a subtraction:

```
private int getNavigationBarHeight(Resources res, Context context) {
        final int apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if((apiLevel >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && apiLevel <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                ||
                (apiLevel >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH && !ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey())
                ) {
            int resourceId = res.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                return res.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The new result is : the window is ok now in *B*, but when shown in *A*, it has a y offset.

The question is, how could I make my window appear ok on both devices

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the exact same problem as you. On my Emulator, the PopupWindow was drawn correctly within the Window's boundaries, thanks to the PopupWindow's `Gravity.NO_GRAVITY`. On my Nexus 7 tablet however, the PopupWindow was displayed below the Device's Status Bar which is displayed at the bottom.

My PopupWindow would show up after I clicked on an ImageButton on my screen, at that ImageButtons y-position (and as width I had `match_parent`). This ImageButton's position could be within Window's boundaries, or just/completely below the Tablet's Bottom Status Bar.

**This is what I came up with:**

What we have:

- The [x, y]-position we gave to the PopupWindow's showAtLocation-method (we only need the y-position in this, which I named `oldY`)

What we calculate:

- The Popup height
- The Status Bar height
- The max possible height to be within Window boundaries (`screenHeight - statusBarHeight - popupHeight`)

What we then check:

- We check if the `oldY` is larger than the `maxY`
- If this is the case, the `newY` will be the `maxY` and we re-draw the PopupWindow. If this isn't the case it means we do nothing and just use the `oldY` as the correct Y-postition.

**NOTE 1:** I made the code for this, but during debugging it turned out the Status Bar's Height is 0 on both my Emulator and my Nexus Tablet, so just using the `screenHeight - popupHeight` was enough for me. Still, I included the code to calculate the Bottom Status Bar Height with a boolean in my Config-file to enable/disable this, in case the app is installed on another tablet in the future.

Here it is in code, I just added the description above to make it clear which approach I used to tackle this problem:

```
// Get the [x, y]-location of the ImageButton
int[] loc = new int[2];
myImageButton.getLocationOnScreen(loc);

// Inflate the popup.xml
LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.popup_layout);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, viewGroup);

// Create the PopupWindow
myPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(ChecklistActivity.this);
myPopupWindow.setContentView(layout);
myPopupWindow.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

... // Some more stuff with the PopupWindow's content

// Clear the default translucent background and use a white background instead
myPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.WHITE));

// Displaying the Pop-up at the specified location
myPopupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, loc[1]);

// Because the PopupWindow is displayed below the Status Bar on some Device's,
// we recalculate it's height:
// Wait until the PopupWindow is done loading by using an OnGlobalLayoutListener:
final int[] finalLoc = loc;
if(layout.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()){
    layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        // This will be called once the layout is finished, prior to displaying it
        // So we can change the y-position of the PopupWindow just before that
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Get the PopupWindow's height
            int popupHeight = layout.getHeight();
            // Get the Status Bar's height
            int statusBarHeight = 0;
            // Enable/Disable this in the Config-file
            // This isn't needed for the Emulator, nor the Nexus 7 tablet
            // Since the calculated Status Bar Height is 0 with both of them
            // and the PopupWindow is displayed at its correct position
            if(D.WITH_STATUS_BAR_CHECK){
                // Check whether the Status bar is at the top or bottom
                Rect r = new Rect();
                Window w = ChecklistActivity.this.getWindow();
                w.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
                int barHeightCheck = r.top;
                // If the barHeightCheck is 0, it means our Status Bar is
                // displayed at the bottom and we need to get it's height
                // (If the Status Bar is displayed at the top, we use 0 as Status Bar Height)
                if(barHeightCheck == 0){
                    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
                    if (resourceId > 0)
                        statusBarHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
                }
            }
            // Get the Screen's height:
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;
            // Get the old Y-position
            int oldY = finalLoc[1];
            // Get the max Y-position to be within Window boundaries
            int maxY = screenHeight - statusBarHeight - popupHeight;
            // Check if the old Y-position is outside the Window boundary
            if(oldY > maxY){
                // If it is, use the max Y-position as new Y-position,
                // and re-draw the PopupWindow
                myPopupWindow.dismiss();
                myPopupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, maxY);
            }

            // Since we don't want onGlobalLayout to continue forever, we remove the Listener here again
            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

**NOTE 2:** I've set the `tag_popup` itself to `width = match_parent; height = wrap_content` on this line:

```
myPopupWindow.setWindowLayoutMode(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and the main layout of this Popup to `width = match_parent; height = match_parent`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE xml>
 <!-- The DOCTYPE above is added to get rid of the following warning:
     "No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document." -->

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/popup_layout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@layout/tag_shape"
     android:padding="@dimen/default_margin">

     ... <!-- Popup's Content (EditTexts, Spinner, TextViews, Button, etc.) -->

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**NOTE 3:** <strike>My app is forced to stay in Portrait mode. I haven't test this in Landscape mode, but I assume some modifications should be made (not sure though).</strike> EDIT: Tested and it also works in Landscape mode on my two devices. I don't know if this also works in Landscape Mode with the Bottom Bar Height enabled.

Hope this helps you and some others with similar problems. Hopefully they will fix PopupWindow's `Gravity` in the future, so it will never be below a Status bar, unless the programmer wants this themselves and change the PopupWindow's settings.

Comment: your answer really helps but I eventually found the problem in my app. it's that my content view in `PopupWindow` has a margin (that is the Y offset in the tablet) to the top edge of the window. I use `View.getLocationOnScreen` to get the offset in onDraw before drawing then everything is ok.

Comment: @suitianshi Ah ok. Glad we both found the solution to our own problems.